# Sudo has stopped working : sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin `sudoers_policy'

Tags: linux, sudo

I have a weird issue with my Raspberry pi - sudo has stopped working. Every time I try to run a command using sudo, i get this:

```
sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin `sudoers_policy'
sudo: unable to load /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so: (null) 
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

Commands without sudo seem to work okay. The file /etc/sudo.conf doesn't exist at all.

This is the system info:

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.4.21-v7+ #911 SMP Thu Sep 15 14:22:38 BST 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Is there a way of fixing this, ideally without formatting the SD card/reinstalling?

Comment: Does /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so exist on your system?

Comment: Yeah, that exists.

Comment: What are the permissions?

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 308944 Jan 11  2016 /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so

Comment: Can you get a root shell by doinf su - and entering your password?

Comment: Unfortunately not, i get "Authentication failure" after entering the password.

Comment: Do you have access to another Linux computer?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately I am not with the pi at the moment so I was hoping I could fix it remotely. If there is no remote option then I'll just have to go to it so that i can work with the SD card.

Comment: A couple of additional things to test: does root have read and exec privileges on each directory to the sudoers.so file (/usr/lib/sudo)? What is the output of ldd /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so? To rule out the obvious what are the most recent changes you have made?

Comment: Root has the read and exec to /usr/lib/sudo. ldd /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so outputs nothing at all. The last things on the pi were apt-get update and apt-get upgrade (which seemed to work). I've not modified the sudo configs or done anything out of ordinary that I know of :).

Comment: the ldd command should give something like this:  linux-vdso.so.1 (0x7ead4000)
        /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so (0x76ebd000)
        libaudit.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libaudit.so.1 (0x76e77000)
        libpam.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpam.so.0 (0x76e5b000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2 (0x76e48000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0x76d07000)
        /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0x54b8e000) sorry for the formatting.

Comment: If you have access to another Linux machine I would try copying a good copy of the /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so file to your SD card.

Comment: It turns out I can't replace the file as I cannot use sudo...

Comment: IIRC you should have full access if you put the card in a Linux box.

Comment: Yeah, i guess I just have to get to the card then. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: No problem that is what we are here for. Unfortunately if that does not work you may have to restore from a recent backup.

Comment: Were there any symbolic links in the path leading to /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so?  Like /usr/lib/sudo -> /someother/place/sudo?

Comment: I had a similar problem with sudo.  It was *very* particular about where it looked for its libraries.  I ended up having to make some symbolc links to /usr/lib so that it would find the ones in question (libz, and libgcc).  I don't know if that's what you've got, but it presents the same way.  I found it by kernel tracing the executable to find what it was doing.  The correct fix for me would have been to recompile it such that it looked in the correct place.  What I did, with my head hung in shame,  was make some symbolic links.

Answer (score 1):

You specified in your question that `/etc/sudo.conf` does not exist, but I don't think it's supposed to. If `/etc/sudoers` does not exist, however, you need one. You can recreate it by putting the SD card into a linux computer and using a text editor as root to fill in the basics:

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

If you have an original copy somewhere, you could copy that in place.

*Update*

Fabian makes a good point in the comments. If you create the file, the permissions need to be correct. When I create the file as root, the default permissions don't allow access to anyone except root's user and group, but the default file has slightly more restrictive permissions. The example below needs to be corrected for wherever the `sudoers` file is located, or just do this as root after booting back up:

```
chmod 440 /etc/sudoers
```

The file should also be owned by root, so if it isn't (for some strange reason) execute this command in the environment and as root:

```
chown root:root /etc/sudoers
```

Comment: addition: permissions of `/etc/sudoers` should be `-r--r----- 1 root root`

Answer (score 1):

I get the same matter. 
The way to resolve the problem is to use the other linux to fix the owner.

For example, you have a ubuntu as a virtual machine on your computer(MacOS or Windows it doesn't matter.) If you have the other raspberry, it is right for this working. You need to use a USB adapter for your micro sd card which is your "pi".

Then, plug the "pi" to your linux machine. Execute the cli `df -h`. You see the `/media` or `/dev` in front of you.

Go into it, `cd /media` or `cd /dev`. Perhaps, your pi not having the machine name, it may be as a series of number to represent your `/boot` and `/`. (Don't go to the wrong way, go to `/`. My operation is on virtual machine, ubuntu and the name is `/media/virtuallmachine/mypie`.)

The last name `mypie` is your "pi" machine name. If you haven't name it, the long number is to replace the name of it.

Run `cd /media/virtuallmachine/mypie` and then run `ls`. You can see the all of directories about `/`. (i.e. etc, usr, var, home, dev and media..etc..)

```
pi@retropie:/usr/lib/sudo $ ls -alh
total 472K
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Mar 14  2018 .
drwxr-xr-x 85 root root 4.0K Dec  8 10:29 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  915 Jun  5  2017 group_file.la
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 9.4K Jun  5  2017 group_file.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  936 Jun  5  2017 libsudo_util.la
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   21 Jun  5  2017 libsudo_util.so -> libsudo_util.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   21 Jun  5  2017 libsudo_util.so.0 -> libsudo_util.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  78K Jun  5  2017 libsudo_util.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  14K Jun  5  2017 sesh
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  897 Jun  5  2017 sudoers.la
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 319K Jun  5  2017 sudoers.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  920 Jun  5  2017 sudo_noexec.la
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 5.3K Jun  5  2017 sudo_noexec.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  927 Jun  5  2017 system_group.la
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 5.4K Jun  5  2017 system_group.so
pi@retropie:/usr/lib/sudo $
```

If you know regex, you can quickly to change the permission. The command line is this-`find . -name "*\.so*" -o -name "*\.la"`". This is output under below.

```
pi@retropie:/usr/lib/sudo $ find . -name "*\.so*" -o -name "*\.la"
./group_file.la
./system_group.so
./sudo_noexec.la
./libsudo_util.so
./sudo_noexec.so
./sudoers.la
./libsudo_util.so.0.0.0
./libsudo_util.la
./libsudo_util.so.0
./sudoers.so
./system_group.la
./group_file.so
pi@retropie:/usr/lib/sudo $
```

The next step is to execute `find . -name "*\.so*" -o -name "*\.la" -exec chmod 644 {} \;`. This is a way to change all file having ".so"(including a ".so" with or without those tailing characters.) or ".la". Behind `-exec`, it is the command such as `cp`, `mv`, `cat` or others. The curly brace `{}` and `\;` must be with this command line(cli) for executing. Without them, it can not be executed. Why? Just Google it.

A site is for practicing regex. (Plus a book or site much better for learning.)
https://www.regexpal.com

==================================================================================

## Above the article, it is enough for you to handle your matter.

## Under below, I wonder why I get this matter.(It's able to be ignored.)

This path `/usr/lib` had been changed to its owner `pi:pi`. If your pi machine has this situation, it is needed to be change to `root:root`.

Under the path-`/usr/lib/`, there are many user library. My situation is all of them being changed to `pi:pi`. So, it should be changed back to `root:root`.

```
pi@retropie:/usr $ ls -alh
total 104K
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root  4.0K Mar 14  2018 .
drwxr-xr-x  21 root root  4.0K Dec 18 13:56 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   48K Dec 25 15:16 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4.0K Dec  2 16:31 games
drwxr-xr-x  94 root root   12K Dec  8 10:33 include
drwxr-xr-x  85 pi   pi    4.0K Dec  8 10:29 lib
drwxrwsr-x  10 root staff 4.0K Dec  6 15:42 local
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   12K Dec 17 18:32 sbin
drwxr-xr-x 220 root root  4.0K Dec 13 10:14 share
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root  4.0K Dec  8 10:54 src
pi@retropie:/usr $
```

Why I get the matter? I am specious on a way I had run "`find /home/pi -type f -group pi -exec chmod 700 {} \;`" and "`find /home/pi -type d -group pi -exec chmod 700 {} \;`". This way is to make my `/home/pi` to be limit their `rwx` permission.

The other way is to change `/etc/fstab` to add a line `#PARTUUID=14a75fe9-02  /home/pi/myweb               ext4    defaults,acl  1       2` for `acl`.

About acl:

https://sites.google.com/site/itmyshare/system-admin-tips-and-tools/acl-on-linux----setfacl-examples

https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ugetfacl.htm